# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in web developer tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, web-crawler

I am currently making an web application, and I am using cheerio.js to crawl some information from a website and want to pass this information to my .html file. The problem is that my .js file which uses cheerio.js works fine(crawling the right infos) but when I put it online on chrome, it shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" in web developer tool.

```js
$('#checkb').on('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  window.location.href = "check.html"
})

const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');

request('https://finance.naver.com/marketindex/exchangeList.nhn', (error, response, html) => {
  let result = [];
  if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const exchange = $('.tit').next();

    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      let a = $(exchange[i]).text();
      result.push(a);
    }
    console.log(result);
  }
})
```

This is my .js file using cheerio.js to crawl information. I am not sure how to make it run on web browser(and on the application). How do I include node.js, cheerio.js and other installation(packages) that is needed to run this application online? not on my computer locally..?
Can anyone give me some advise? Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: You can't include node in client-side code - it's a fundamentally different JS environment. One runs on the server, the other in the browser - and you can't bridge that gap (other than by making HTTP request, often with Ajax) just because you're using the same language for both.

Comment: Node js runs on the server side and not on client side. You can instantiate a server in a separate file  and make an http request by using npm packages like axios or fetch.